# Any way to convert a regular string in ActionScript 3 to a ByteArray of Latin-1 Character Codes?

Tags: actionscript-3, erlang, utf-16, iso-8859-1

I am having no problem converting a string to a byteArray of UTF-16 encoded characters, but the application I am trying to communicate with (written in Erlang) only understands Latin-1 encoding. Is there any way of producing a byteArray full of Latin-1 character codes from a string within Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

byteArray.writeMultiByte(string, "iso-8859-1");

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeMultiByte()

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would do the trick as well, but it actually manages to write the characters themselves instead of the character values. I may be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between the "characters themselves" and "character values" is?

Comment: Characters are stored in memory as their encoding representation (usually ASCII or UTF-8). For example, the letter "N" is represented as hexadecimal value "4e" in memory.