# How to convert AS3 ByteArray into wchar_t const* filename? (Adobe Alchemy)

Tags: c++, c, actionscript-3, adobe, alchemy

How to convert AS3 `ByteArray` into `wchar_t const* filename`?

So in my C code I have a function waiting for a file with `void fun (wchar_t const* filename)` how to send to that function my `ByteArray`? (Or, how should I re-write my function?)

Comment: I'm not really into this subject, but I suppose this link may provide you with some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360353/any-way-to-convert-a-regular-string-in-actionscript-3-to-a-bytearray-of-latin-1-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A four month old question.  Better late than never?

To convert a ByteArray to a String in AS3, there are two ways depending on how the String was stored.  Firstly, if you use `writeUTF` it will write an `unsigned short` representing the String's length first, then write out the string data.  The string is easiest to recover this way.  Here's how it's done in AS3:

```
byteArray.position = 0;
var str:String = byteArray.readUTF();
```

Alternatively, `toString` also works in this case.  The second way to store is with `writeUTFBytes`.  This won't write the length to the beginning, so you'll need to track it independantly somehow.  It sounds like you want the entire ByteArray to be a single String, so you can use the ByteArray's `length`.

```
byteArray.position = 0;
var str:String = byteArray.readUTFBytes(byteArray.length);
```

Since you want to do this with Alchemy, you just need to convert the above code.  Here's a conversion of the second example:

```
std::string batostr(AS3_Val byteArray) {
    AS3_SetS(byteArray, "position", AS3_Int(0));
    return AS3_StringValue(AS3_CallS("readUTFBytes", byteArray,
        AS3_Array("AS3ValType", AS3_GetS(byteArray, "length")) ));
}
```

This has a ridiculous amount of memory leaks, of course, since I'm not calling `AS3_Release` anywhere.  I use a RAII wrapper for `AS3_Val` in my own code... for the sake of my sanity.  As should you.

Anyway, the `std::string` my function returns will be UTF-8 multibyte.  Any standard C++ technique for converting to wide characters should work from here. (search the site for endless reposts)  I suggest leaving it is as it, though.  I can't think of any advantage to using wide characters on this platform.

Comment: RAII wrapper... hm... could you provide any links?

Comment: @Jak: Make a class where one constructor takes a AS3_Val and stores it.  Its copy constructor copies the other object's AS3_Val and calls `AS3_Acquire`.  In the destructor it calls `AS3_Release`.  That's the basic functionallity.